# Extracting strings from output in Linux console

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, tr

I have been trying to extract specific strings from the output in Linux

For example:

```
ps -eo pid,args | grep PRD_ | egrep startscen.sh | more
```

gives the following output

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biwx7.png]

(Full-size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biwx7.png)

I am aware awk, sed, tr can be used to extract details like PID but I am not sure how to write a query to get exactly the pid of the row where the fourth column has a specific string like 'PROCESS_ALL_BETS'

Or how do I extract every character after _NAME=?

Comment: Posting a brief text snippet would be worlds better than a screenshot, especially one which isn't in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk to the rescue.

```
ps -eo pid,args | awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ && $4 ~ /PROCESS_ALLBETS/'
```

(In the image, you have `PROCESS_ALLBETS`, so I guess that's what you actually want, even though your text says `PROCESS_ALL_BETS`.)

This selects for printing every line which matches all the following conditions:

- `/PRD_/` -- there is a "PRD_" somewhere in the line.  Maybe you would tighten this to something like `$6 ~ /^-NAME=PRD_/` to only match on the beginning of the sixth field.
- `/stratscen\.sh/` -- there is a match for this regex somewhere on the line.  Again, for improved precision, you might want to change this to `$3 ~ /startscen\.sh/` or even `$3 == "startscen.sh"` if you only want exact matches.
- `$4 ~ /PROCESS_ALLBETS/` -- the fourth field matches this regular expression.

The above will simply print all matching lines.  To print just the first field and the eight field with the prefix `-SESSION_NAME=` removed, add something like

```
{ n=$8; sub(/^-SESSION_NAME=/,"",n); print $1, n }
```

just before the closing single quote.

Comment: Also, I wanted to list all the PIDs and their corresponding scripts for example

Comment: 462 DEQUEUE_ALL_EVENTS_PLSQL

Comment: Your requirements are not very clear.  If you can clarify your question with more details, please do.  For the time being, the immediate suspicion is that you want `PROCESS_ALLBETS` instead of `PROCESS_ALL_BETS`.

Comment: I appended your script <br/> ps -eo pid,args | grep PRD_ | egrep startscen.sh | more | awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ && $4 ~ /PROCESS_ALL_BETS/{ n=$8; sub(/^-SESSION_NAME=/,"",n); print $1, n }'
<br/> But I don't see an output.

Comment: In the screenshot I have shared, I see rows listing different processes which have the following regular expressions "PRD_" and "./startscen.sh" - Now I need a script where I pass a string like PRO'' fetch the row that corresponds to the PROCESS_ALL_BET the output is 13561.

Comment: The Awk script should replace your `grep` pipeline; what you have is a [Useless Use of `grep`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep). But it should work if the regexes are correct. Did you try with `ALLBETS` instead of `ALL_BETS`?

Comment: I edited the answer to have `ALLBETS` instead, and added an explanation of what the script does.

Comment: Okay, I understood the confusion. When I ran, ps -eo pid,args | awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ && $4 ~ /PROCESS_ALLBETS/' - it is giving the correct results. And I was trying to find out if the text after "-SESSION_NAME=******" can be extracted? I know, grep cannot manipulate text like awk, but can it be used to get the same output?

Comment: I just read the updated response. Thanks a lot, this shall do :)